# selecting columns from a set of names with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to make subsets of a large data frame based on whether the column names are in an externally defined set. So I'm starting with something like:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> y <- c("a","b","c")
> z <- c(4,5,6)
> 
> df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
> df
  x y z
1 1 a 4
2 2 b 5
3 3 c 6

chosen_columns <- c(x,y)
```

And I'm attempting to use this much to end up with:

```
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
```

It seems like using `select()` from dplyr should be able to handle this perfectly, but I'm not sure what the arguments would be to get that. Something like:

```
df_chosen <- df %>%
  select(is.element(___,chosen_columns))
```

I'm just not sure what would go in the ___ there.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally you want `df %>% select(all_of(chosen_columns))` (or `any_of()` if you want to take whatever's there without an error if some are missing).

Comment: But use `chosen_columns = c("x", "y")` not `c(x, y)`. The latter actually sticks x and y together giving you `"1", "2", "3", "a", "b", "c"` which is not what you want.

Comment: This is just what I needed! The code I had to build the bigger sets of names was already creating them as strings, so it worked as is. Thanks!

Comment: To make your selection code more robust and silence the message, use `all_of()` to force the external vector. It is critical to refer to a external vector for column selection. For historical reasons it is working. See the comments of Gregor Thomas and have a look here <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>

Answer (score 4):

`c(x, y)` is not a vector of two columns: it's combining your *objects* `x` and `y` into a vector of characters: `c("1", "2", "3", "a","b","c")`.

You may want to create a vector of column *names* and then pass it directly to `select()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

chosen_columns <- c("x", "y")

df |> select(all_of(chosen_columns))
```

(Thank you, Gregor Thomas, for the advice to wrap column names in `all_of()`).

Comment: It is **much** safer to use `all_of` or `any_of`---hence the cautionary note that prints once per session if you don't.